# c#.NET and sprintf syntax

Tags: c#, .net

How would this code be translated into C#, specifically how would `sprintf` be implemented in C#?

```
string output = "The user %s logged in";
string loggedIn = "is";
string loggedOut = "isn't";

if (TheUser.CheckStatus())
{
    output = sprintf(output, loggedIn);
}
else
{
    output = sprintf(output, loggedOut);
}

return output;
```

I'm expecting to see `"The user isn't logged in"` if `TheUser.CheckStatus()` is `false`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Check out [string.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) and here is a version of your code using it:

```
string output = "The user {0} logged in";
string loggedIn = "is";
string loggedOut = "isn't";

if (TheUser.CheckStatus())
{
    output = string.Format(output, loggedIn);
}
else
{
    output = string.Format(output, loggedOut);
}

return output;
```

Or more simply: (using a ternary expression)

```
string output = "The user {0} logged in";

return TheUser.CheckStatus() 
    ? string.Format(output, "is")
    : string.Format(output, "isn't");
```

Comment: Or as a single liner: `return string.Format("The user {0} logged in", TheUser.CheckStatus() ? "is" : "isn't");`

Answer (score 6):

The whole `printf` family of functions in C is replaced by [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The same interface is also exposed in for example `Console.WriteLine()`.

```
 string output = "The user {0} logged in";
 string loggedIn = "is";
 string loggedOut = "isn't";


 output = string.Format(output, loggedIn);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to stick with %s,%d....

```
string sprintf(string input,params object[] inpVars)
{
    int i=0;
    input=Regex.Replace(input,"%.",m=>("{"+ i++/*increase have to be on right side*/ +"}"));
    return string.Format(input,inpVars);
}
```

You can now do

```
sprintf("hello %s..Hi %d","foofoo",455);
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative. Good to know!

Comment: I needed that :), thanks.. Also do not forget to include `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`

Comment: @semoLi, in an edit, suggests that it should be `input=Regex.Replace(input,"%.",m=>("{"+ i++/*increase have to be on right side*/ +"}"));`  Seems correct, compare https://dotnetfiddle.net/1fvvqD to https://dotnetfiddle.net/nu0dBY

Answer (score 4):

With C# 6 you can use the formattable string:

```
if (TheUser.CheckStatus())
{
    output = $"The user {loggedIn} logged in"
}
```

The `{loggedIn}` inside the string is the variable name that you have defined.

Also, you have intellisense inside the curly braces to pick the variable name.

Comment: Is it possible to "load" such a string? For example, getting the string from somewhere else, and then somehow using it in code?

Answer (score 3):

[string.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx) to the rescue

```
string output = "The user {0} logged in";
string loggedIn = "is";
string loggedOut = "isn't";

output = (TheUser.CheckStatus() ? string.Format(output, loggedIn) : 
                                  string.Format(output, loggedOut));
return output;
```

See also this very fundamental article on [composite formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

EDIT: shorter

```
return string.Format(output, (TheUser.CheckStatus() ? loggedIn : loggedOut));
```

Comment: sprintf... obey me or i'll put you on diaper detail!!

Comment: Love the shorthand if statement. Thanks for that syntax too :)

Comment: @JamesT yes very useful, made shorter

Answer (score 0):

Anirudha already wrote the solution but I cannot add comments so I am posting it as an answer. It needs to be `int i=-1;` or it will throw an exception.

```
string sprintf(string input,params object[] inpVars)
{
    int i=-1;
    input=Regex.Replace(input,"%.",m=>("{"+ ++i +"}"));
    return string.Format(input,inpVars);
}
```