# print string to a byte pointer in c#

Tags: c#, c, pointers, translate

I'm tring to translate C code to C# and I stumbled upon a line of code which I'm having problems translating.

```
sprintf((char*)&u8FirmareBuffer[0x1C0] + strlen((char*)&u8FirmareBuffer[0x1C0]), ".B%s", argv[3]);
```

specifically this line.
u8FirmwareBuffer is a unsigned char array in C, a byte array in C# I would guess.
argv[3] is a string.
How can I translate this line to C#.

Thank you for your help.

Edit: This has been marked as a duplicate, but I think they differenciate because I am using pointers which don't work with the solutions presented on the marked post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c#.NET and sprintf syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14482341/c-net-and-sprintf-syntax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
string myString = "This is my string";
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int offset = 0;

    // if you pass a byte buffer to the constructor of a memorystream, it will use that, don't forget that it cannot grow the buffer.
using (var memStream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
{
    // you can even seek to a specific position
    memStream.Seek(offset, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    // check your encoding..
    var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myString);

    // write it on the current offset in the memory stream
    memStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```

---

It's also possible with a [StreamWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
string myString = "This is my string";
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int offset = 0;

// if you pass a byte buffer to the constructor.....(see above)
using (var memStream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memStream))
{
    // you can even seek to a specific position
    memStream.Seek(offset, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    streamWriter.Write(myString);
    streamWriter.Flush();

    // don't forget to flush before you seek again
}
```

Comment: Are you attempting to avoid `unsafe`? For fixed offsets you could also [use struct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/792735/1997232)

Comment: I don't see anything that's struct related. Yes, I'd rather avoid unsafe if is not needed

Comment: Thanks, this helped resolve some errors and understand some stuff. I won't be able to test it now since my manager didn't give me anything to test it yet, but thank you for you help!